# Is it possible to perform group_by operation on a pandas GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to perform a very costly groupby operation on a large pandas dataframe, and wanted to know if it is possible to first group by the first n columns of the dataframe, and then depending on a condition in my code, re-group the resulting object on another column, and therefore add the new column to the index of the resulting object.

Currently the DataFrame looks like this:

```
compound_data = {
    'n1': {0: 'n1_value_1', 1: 'n1_value_2', 2: 'n1_value_3'},
    'n2': {0: 'n2_value_1', 1: 'n2_value_2', 2: 'n2_value_3'},
    'n3': {0: 'n3_value_1', 1: 'n3_value_2', 2: 'n3_value_3'},
    'n4': {0: 'n4_value_1', 1: 'n4_value_2', 2: 'n4_value_3'},
}
compound_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(compound_data)
```

The block of code that calls the groupby looks like this:

```
categorical_columns = ['n3', 'n4']

for column in categorical_columns:
    counts = compound_data_frame.groupby(
                ['n1', 'n2', column]).size()
```

This means that I end up grouping by n1 and n2 twice, which I fear is unnecessarily costly in terms of execution time. I would like to group by n1 and n2 only once, and then afterwards somehow group the results of the first grouping by n3, and then to repeat this process for n4.

so if I were to  first group on columns "n1" and "n2", the resulting object might look like this (let's call this object "first_grouping"):

```
                      n3
index 
n1_value/n2_value    n3_value
```

I want to be able to group this by n3 afterwards and count the result, in order to end up with this:

```
                                count
index 
n1_value/n2_value/n3_value      1
```

and afterwards I want to take the first_grouping object, but this time I want to group by n4 instead of n3, so that the end result looks like this:

```
                                count
index 
n1_value/n2_value/n4_value      1
```

I need to be able to access this index that contains all the columns that the object has been grouped on, because these counts are used to update another dataframe that contains the results from these operations. This 2nd dataframe has a multi index that looks like this:

```
                            count
index 
n1_value/n2_value/n3_value      1 
n1_value/n2_value/n4_value      1
```

Using the original implementation with a new, all encompassing groupby operation is much too slow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, yes you can do nested `groupby`, because in the example below, in the `apply`, the variable `x` is a dataframe, so you can perform same operations (like `groupby`) on it as on any dataframe:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'n1':list('a'*8), 'n2':list('b'*4+'c'*4), 
                    'n3':list('d'*2+'e'*2)*2, 0:range(8)})

print (df_.groupby(['n1','n2']).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('n3')[[0]].count()))
          0
n1 n2 n3   
a  b  d   2
      e   2
   c  d   2
      e   2
```

although in this case, a simple `df_.groupby(['n1','n2','n3'])[[0]].count()` would do the same.

EDIT: a better example with a function that does not do the same thing depending on the size of the grouped dataframe:

```
def f(x):
    gr = x.groupby('n3')[[0]]
    return gr.count() if len(x)>=4 else gr.tail(1)

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'n1':list('a'*8), 'n2':list('b'*6+'c'*2),
                    'n3':list('d'*7+'e'), 0:range(8)})

print (df_.groupby(['n1','n2']).apply(f))
          0
n1 n2 n3   
a  b  d   6 #returned the count
   c  6   6 #returned the last value of the group
      7   7 #...
```

EDIT2: regarding the new information in the question, I think you could try to do only a `groupby` on n1 and n2 and then `value_counts` on columns from categorical_columns, `concat` results like:

```
gr = compound_data_frame.groupby(['n1', 'n2'])
df_ = pd.concat([gr[col].value_counts() for col in categorical_columns]).to_frame('count')
df_.index.names=['n1', 'n2', None]
```

Comment: @BenT I'm getting as KeyError on .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('n3')[[0]], did you try this code yourself?

Comment: @BenT never mind it was my mistake, your solution works but it's very slow, so I opted for creating a multi-index followed by groupby.

Comment: @Boris add more explanation to your question, the way it is now is a bit too general to help with a better answer. But indeed nested `groupby` won't be especially efficient if the dataframe is big and/or have a lot of groups :)

Comment: I don't know what else to add to clarify the question. Your solution works, it's just that it's even slower than doing a grouby repeatedly for every additional column

Comment: @Boris by this I mean tell us what your code really do. From what you said: "and then depending on a condition in my code", I assume you are not just `groupby` n columns then `groupby` another column to simply `count`, otherwise I am not sure to understand the point of your question because the way it is right now it is hard to give a faster solution than `groupby`, especially if you want a fast solution maybe the bottleneck is not the `groupby` but what you perform inside. And some action could be done at the dataframe level not the grouped level that is faster generally :)

Comment: @BenT I've updated the question to add more details. Thanks for sticking with me and please let me know if anything is still unclear. :)

Comment: @Boris ok see my edit2, if I undertand correclyt what your code did :)